# Insert into SQLITE TABLE inside FOR loop using Java in Android getting NPE error?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

i am getting data from my Service and when trying to insert into TABLE i am getting exception....While my first row is correctly printing on Log and just after that error : **error is on this LOC:
 db.execSQL(query);** 
public class ProgramDBHelperActivity extends Activity {

```
Context context;
SQLiteDatabase db;


    private void getParametersData(String parameter)
            {
                try
            {
                String getParametersData_String  = ServerRequest1.sendRequest(url,parameter);
                String[] getParametersData_Str_Array = getParametersData_String.split("<br />");

                 for(int i=0;i<getParametersData_Str_Array.length;i++)
                 {
        Log.i("getParametersData_Str_Array :",getParametersData_Str_Array[i]);

    String query =  "INSERT  INTO parameterTable(ID,param_type,cash_code,param_description) " +  "VALUES ("+getParametersData_Str_Array[i]+");";
    Log.i("query result",""+query);
    db.execSQL(query);
    Log.i("news Save", "" + db);
   }
   }
   catch (JSONException e) 
   {
    errorMessage = getString(R.string.ExceptionGeneral);
  ExceptionHandler.logException(e);
  e.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch (SocketException e) {
   errorMessage = getString(R.string.ExceptionNetworkProblem);
   ExceptionHandler.logException(e);
   e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                errorMessage = getString(R.string.ExceptionGeneral);
                ExceptionHandler.logException(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                errorMessage = getString(R.string.ExceptionGeneral);
                ExceptionHandler.logException(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
```

HERE IS THE LOG:

> 12-19 04:39:42.234: I/query result(4772): INSERT  INTO parameterTable(ID,param_type,cash_code,param_description) VALUES (1,"product group","12345","Service Spares");
>   12-19 04:39:42.234: W/System.err(4772): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   12-19 04:39:42.234: W/System.err(4772):     at com.survey.management.activity.ProgramDBHelperActivity$ReqGetParameter.getParametersData(ProgramDBHelperActivity.java:146)
>   12-19 04:39:42.234: W/System.err(4772):     at com.survey.management.activity.ProgramDBHelperActivity$ReqGetParameter.doInBackground(ProgramDBHelperActivity.java:128)
>   12-19 04:39:42.234: W/System.err(4772):     at com.survey.management.activity.ProgramDBHelperActivity$ReqGetParameter.doInBackground(ProgramDBHelperActivity.java:1)
>   12-19 04:39:42.234: W/System.err(4772):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/taplaw.log: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at com.survey.management.util.ExceptionHandler.logException(ExceptionHandler.java:55)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at com.survey.management.activity.ProgramDBHelperActivity$ReqGetParameter.getParametersData(ProgramDBHelperActivity.java:167)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at com.survey.management.activity.ProgramDBHelperActivity$ReqGetParameter.doInBackground(ProgramDBHelperActivity.java:128)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at com.survey.management.activity.ProgramDBHelperActivity$ReqGetParameter.doInBackground(ProgramDBHelperActivity.java:1)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   12-19 04:39:42.239: W/System.err(4772):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     ... 12 more
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at com.survey.management.activity.ProgramDBHelperActivity$ReqGetParameter.getParametersData(ProgramDBHelperActivity.java:146)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at com.survey.management.activity.ProgramDBHelperActivity$ReqGetParameter.doInBackground(ProgramDBHelperActivity.java:128)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at com.survey.management.activity.ProgramDBHelperActivity$ReqGetParameter.doInBackground(ProgramDBHelperActivity.java:1)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   12-19 04:39:42.244: W/System.err(4772):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Comment: Likely `db` is null - the code doesn't show where it is declared/initialized.

Comment: Don't use `execSQL`, use `insert` instead. > http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `db` is not initialized and therefore `null`. If you're using the usual `SQLiteOpenHelper` pattern, initialize it with

```
db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```